# copy address from pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I have following code :

```
    /* Window size in bytes. */
static  uint32_t size = 0;
    /* Window address. */
static  uint32_t address = 0;
    /* Memory Base Address */   
static uint8_t *sharedMemory=NULL;

sharedMemory = memalign(size, size);

void rioShardMemoryWindowGet (uint8_t *baseAddr,uint32_t *memorySize,uint32_t *windowAddress  )
{
    *baseAddr=(int)sharedMemory;
    printf("sharedMemory: #%x",sharedMemory);
    *memorySize=size;
    *windowAddress=address;
}
rioShardMemoryWindowGet(&baseAddr0, &baseSize, &(Addrs.virtualBaseAddr));
printf("baseAddr0 : #%x",baseAddr0);
```

I have no clue why baseAddr0 is 0 in the second printf, while in the first sharedMemory is 0x500000.

Comment: why is the casting *baseAddr=(int)sharedMemory; necessary? aren't they both uint8_t?

Comment: also, can you show baseAddr0 definition please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I understand your problem.

You're trying to store the address number in baseAddr0, am I right? (not sure the reasons but this is the only thing I came up with).

The reason that a 0x500000 is showing as a 0 is because a uint8_t has not enough bits to represent an address and so it's "culling it down" to only 1 byte (therefore showing a 0).

Change the baseAddr to a uint32_t and voila, everything works.

Anyways, the reason the other posters are telling you to use a pointer to pointer is because what you *seem* to be doing is weird, unless you're planning on using the address for something special such as displaying it or using as an offset, perhaps?

p.s.: you're also going to need to change this line

```
*baseAddr=(uint32_t)sharedMemory;
```

edit: your code should look like this to get what you want:

```
    /* Window size in bytes. */
static  uint32_t size = 0;
    /* Window address. */
static  uint32_t address = 0;
    /* Memory Base Address */   
static uint8_t *sharedMemory=NULL;

sharedMemory = memalign(size, size);

void rioShardMemoryWindowGet (uint32_t *baseAddr,uint32_t *memorySize,uint32_t     *windowAddress  )
{
    *baseAddr=(uint32_t)sharedMemory;
    printf("sharedMemory: #%x",sharedMemory);
    *memorySize=size;
    *windowAddress=address;
}
rioShardMemoryWindowGet(&baseAddr0, &baseSize, &(Addrs.virtualBaseAddr));
printf("baseAddr0 : #%x",baseAddr0);
```

The reason why you NEED an uint32 to store the numeric address is because addresses are 32 bits, and that's the reason why you see a 0 using an 8 bit value, because 0x500000 maps to 0x00 to a byte

Comment: Yes your right. That's what I want. But sharedMemory is also uint8_t so it should work. But I tried your clue anyway --> no success

Comment: no, no, an address needs 32 bits, it won't work with you using uint8_t because you're losing information... I'll update the above code to show you how to do it

Comment: maybe you can check the sizes of pointers with `sizeof` operator.

Comment: that's also an option, just don't use an int8, you're asking to lose information that way

Comment: actually, this code will give different result on different architectures. If you want to build a portable code, this might not be a correct way to do it ! For example 32-bit and 64-bit architectures? For I think it is common to have `uint32_t *` a 32-bit variable, but on 64-bit architecture it can be of 64-bits ! or 8-bit architecture, it can be of 8-bits.

Comment: yes, agreed, take this code as a partial solution to explain the problem you're having, not as a universal solution.

Answer (score 1):

`rioShardMemoryWindowGet` should accept `uint8_t **baseAddrPtr` if you want it to modify `baseAddr0`. Then you'll have `*baseAddr = sharedMemory` without a cast.

Comment: But I just want, that baseAddr0 has the address sharedMemory is pointing to

Comment: What I propose is equivalent to assigning `baseAddr0 = sharedMemory;` outside the function. I believe it's what you wanted, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You must pass a pointer to pointer as a function argument.
Only then you will be able to store the value in it. In your case, you tried to store the address of `sharedMemory` in `baseAddr[0]` location.

```
/* Window size in bytes. */
static  uint32_t size = 0;
    /* Window address. */
static  uint32_t address = 0;
    /* Memory Base Address */   
static uint8_t *sharedMemory=NULL;

sharedMemory = memalign(size, size);

void rioShardMemoryWindowGet (uint8_t **baseAddr,uint32_t *memorySize,uint32_t *windowAddress  )
{
    *baseAddr=sharedMemory;
    printf("sharedMemory: #%x",sharedMemory);
    *memorySize=size;
    *windowAddress=address;
}
uint8_t *baseAddr0;
rioShardMemoryWindowGet(&baseAddr0, &baseSize, &(Addrs.virtualBaseAddr));
printf("baseAddr0 : #%x",baseAddr0);
```

Comment: And how can I store the address sharedMemory is pointing at in baseAddr?

Comment: if you read the code, you will be doing it inside the function `rioShardMemoryWindowGet`. you pass the address oo the pointer baseAddr0 to the function in the function call. the first statement does the job you are asking for. I suggest you do a step by step debugging where you inspect the memory locations and variables to understand the concept.